# Shortcut key to close current Opera window in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

I usually browse with multiple Opera windows, each with multiple tabs. On Windows, I can close a single Opera window and all its tabs with <kbd>ALT</kbd> - <kbd>F4</kbd>. Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut for Opera on OS X?

I'm looking for something between <kbd>command</kbd> - <kbd>w</kbd> (which closes only a single Opera tab) and <kbd>command</kbd> - <kbd>q</kbd> (which closes all Opera windows). Clicking the red "close" orb gets the results I want, but I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for OS X (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for those using Windows/Linux) should do the trick.

But you can easily find out, just go to *Preferences > Advanced > Shortcuts*, select your keyboard setup, click *Edit*, and type "close" in the search field, this will show you all shortcuts that close something, so you should be able to work it out from those results.

Comment: Both [command]-[shift]-[w] and [Alt]-[F4] work on OS X~ Nice suggestion to check the preferences! I only thought of checking http://help.opera.com/Mac/11.60/en/keyboard.html

Comment: That's the great thing about Opera - even if there wasn't an existing keyboard shortcut available, you could probably roll your own. Glad you got it to work :-)

Answer (score 1):

⌘ + Shift + W   will close your current Opera window

Reference : http://help.opera.com/Mac/11.00/en/keyboard.html